# Tips for not repeat code between an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dry

I am still building programming logic and I would like to know if this code I've built is the "best possible" or if you guys have any known technique for reducing it.

This is the code, the difference is on the second line of each `function()`:

```
var Run = {
            closeAll : function(){
                $('body').removeClass('slider-active');
                $('[slider-id]').removeClass('active');
                _.getOverlay.removeClass('active');
                _.getWrapper.css(
                    {
                        'left'      : '',
                        'transform' : ''
                    }
                );
            },

            closeThis : function(){
                $('body').removeClass('slider-active');
                _.getSlider.removeClass('active');
                _.getOverlay.removeClass('active');
                _.getWrapper.css(
                    {
                        'left'      : '',
                        'transform' : ''
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

Also, please let me know if I wasn't especific enough or if there is already an Question for that (although i've searched it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it by using one single function and using a parameter to check if all should be toggled or not.

The code:

```
var Run = {
  // Use a boolean parameter
  close : function (all) {
    $('body').removeClass('slider-active');

    // Use the ternary operator
    all ? $('[slider-id]').removeClass('active') : _.getSlider.removeClass('active');

    _.getOverlay.removeClass('active');
    _.getWrapper.css({
      'left'      : '',
      'transform' : ''
    });
  }
}
```

The usage:

- toggle all:

  ```
  Run.close(true);
  ```

  or

  ```
  Run.close(1);
  ```
- toggle one

  ```
  Run.close(false);
  ```

  or

  ```
  Run.close(0);
  ```

  or

  ```
  Run.close();
  ```

Comment: Hey! thanks for your answer, it is a really good way to solve this problem. Also, I don't know if this is allowed here but... I'm kinda new here and if you could please upvote my question so I can upvote other stuff, it would be nice. Thanks again anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Call `close` and pass true if you would like to close *all*:

```
var Run = {
  close: function(all = false) {
    $('body').removeClass('slider-active');
    (all) ?
       $('[slider-id]').removeClass('active')
       : _.getSlider.removeClass('active');
    _.getOverlay.removeClass('active');
    _.getWrapper.css({
      'left': '',
      'transform': ''
    });
  },
}
```

The ternary operator is a simple way to execute a quick binary test. A default value is set for `all` so the current slider is affected by rule and all sliders by exception.